# Free source of corporate bond data?

Tags: bonds, online-data-source, market-data

Are there any free sources of corporate bond data?

More specifically, I would like information about new/upcoming issues (but if something like this exists for secondary markets I would be interested in that as well).

I would prefer that the data be conveniently accessible through HTTP requests or at least downloadable as a spreadsheet or csv file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the data are accessible as a CSV file, but try [FINRA's Advanced Screener](http://cxa.gtm.idmanagedsolutions.com/finra/bondcenter/advancedscreener.aspx). It allows you to search for government, corporate, or municipal bonds using a wide range of criteria. FINRA also publishes [TRACE Market Aggregate Information](http://cxa.gtm.idmanagedsolutions.com/finra/BondCenter/TRACEMarketAggregateStats.aspx), which lists the most active investment grade debt securities and information about them.

For general information on both domestic and international debt markets, the [Bank for International Settlements](http://www.bis.org/statistics/secstats.htm) is a good place to start. They offer data in CSV format, although it isn't as specific as the data from FINRA's screener. For information about the US corporate bond market as a whole, you can also use the [Federal Reserve Economic Data](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/categories/32348) series of corporate bond data. FRED lists over a hundred series of yields on various classes and ratings of debt securities, all of which are available in CSV format, as well in XML format through an API.

I found a site that lists [101 Free Resources for Bond Investors](http://www.learnbonds.com/101-free-resources-for-bond-investors/#16); one section is devoted solely to bond market data. They list data sources like the FINRA data I linked to before, as well as sources specific to certain types of bonds, e.g. municipal bonds, Treasuries, corporate bonds, etc.